# 1080Ti with V100 in the same system, V100 is not detected

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04 system in which I installed both a Geforce 1080Ti and a Tesla V100.

I updated the driver to 396.37

With both in, lspci sees both but nvidia-smi sees only the 1080Ti
If I remove the 1080Ti, the V100 is now detected by nvidia-smi.

If I put 2 1080Tis in, both work and are detected by nvidia-smi.

I couldn't find anywhere that state that a Geforce and Tesla shouldn't work together. Is this a fact? If not, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found in logs:

```
Jul 11 17:09:41 gpu-006 kernel: [    7.902609] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
Jul 11 17:09:41 gpu-006 kernel: [    7.902609] NVRM: BAR1 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:1a:00.0)
Jul 11 17:09:41 gpu-006 kernel: [    7.902611] NVRM: The system BIOS may have misconfigured your GPU.
Jul 11 17:09:41 gpu-006 kernel: [    7.902616] nvidia: probe of 0000:1a:00.0 failed with error -1
```

So I updated the bios of the server. And voila all fixed, both are now detected.

Comment: where did you find the logs?

Comment: var/log/syslog
Or
/var/log/messages

We've had this issue on multiple servers. Bios upgrade was always the fix.